# while loop not adding data to each loops newly created object? in java

Tags: java, while-loop, instantiation, setter

Hi everyone once again thanks for taking the time to look at my issue.

I am trying to create a program that keeps track of employees and the diffrent departments that they are working in.

The program first reads from a text file all the initial data to get the program going. The program then has a while loop within a while loop. The first loop will read the department details and then create the department

in then the next (inner) while loop it reads all the employees accosiated with this department,It then after reading the details of the employee creates the employee and adds it to the previously created department to say this is the department I work in.

after adding all the employees to the department, it then exits that inner loop and sends the department with the employees inside it to the mainDriver for storage. It does this for the remaining departments again adding their associated employees and so on.

The problem Is: it seems to create each department okay and add it to the mainDriver, but all the employees are added to the first department and the remaining department are left empty. Which is not the way it should work as their are several employees in each  department.
Why is it not moving on to the next department as the new Department is instantiated??

Could I please have some help to see where I may be going wrong.

this is the code that read in the data.

```
 while  (index < numberOfDepartmentsToRead ) 
{
        String depName1    = inFile.nextLine();
        String location1     = inFile.nextLine();
        String numberOfEmps = inFile.nextLine();
        int    numberOfEmps1 = Integer.parseInt(numberOfEmps);
        Department newDepartment = new Department(depName1 , location1);

    while (i < numberOfEmps1 )
    {
        String fName     = inFile.nextLine();
        String lName     = inFile.nextLine();
        String gender    = inFile.nextLine();
        String address   = inFile.nextLine();
        String   payLevel  = inFile.nextLine(); 
        int dPayLevel = Integer.parseInt(payLevel);
        Employee employeesFromList = new Employee(randomIDno, fName, lName, gender, dPayLevel);
        newDepartment.setAddEmp(employeesFromList, randomIDno);
        i++;
    }

    i = 0;
    index++;
    MainDriver.setDepartmentToSystem(newDepartment);        
}
```

the employee is passed to this method in the departments class

```
public static void setAddEmp(Employee theEmp, int idNumber)
{
    employeesInThisDepartment.add(theEmp);
    employeeMap.put(idNumber, theEmp);
}
```

the department is added to the mainDriver classes storage method which is this

```
public static void setDepartmentToSystem(Department theDepartment)
        {

            allDepartments.add(theDepartment);
        }
```

Comment: I assume that i is initialized to zero before the first loop?

Comment: I repeat my question from the other day--what resource(s) are you using to learn Java? It seems like a lot of issues are basic, language-level issues, quickly solvable with a Java basics overview.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void setAddEmp(Employee theEmp, int idNumber)
```

Why is it **static**? Make it instance method.

Make `employeesInThisDepartment` instance variable instead of **static**.

Comment: only because if it isnt static I get the error cannot reference from static context,

Comment: could this b causing the issue though?

Comment: @Binyomin: static means it belongs to class. Not all instance will have their own.

Comment: but when I make it static it causes memore issues then its worth. oh well I suppose I do not have a choice.  haha

Comment: I am now removing most static declarations in methods which are static. and I am now getting the error "exception in main thread incompatibleclass change error expected static  method mainDriver.setEmployee".  why would it expect a static??

Comment: @Binyomin: The code you have posted so far is very limited to tell what you are really doing? Why don't you post the whole class involved here.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check your use of `static`.  It is difficult to know without seeing all your code but I wonder if `setAddEmp` should *not* be a static method.

Answer (score 1):

Your `employeesInThisDepartment` is a `static` variable, whereas you need one per-`Department`.

Each `Department` should have its own instance, with an `employees` property, to which the department's employees are added. Similarly, the method to add an employee to the department should be an instance method, not static.

Comment: Thanks again Dave
 sorry to be a pain again, but How would I code it differently to what I have got now, so that each department has its own instance?

Comment: @Binyomin No apologies necessary :) You're already creating a new instance, it's just that the `Department` class hasn't been coded like it's *expecting* to be instantiated. As others and I said, make fewer things static.

Comment: but when I make it static it causes memore issues then its worth. oh well I suppose I do not have a choice. Now that you mention it, it makes sense a static class will cause all creations of it to be added only to it.hmmm i will have to make it work without static.

thanks

Comment: @Binyomin But the data model is such that there are multiple departments. This is why I'm encouraging you to check out some Java-the-language basics, because this is critical, foundational stuff that you'll use every single day you're developing, whether in Java or another class-based OO language.

Comment: Yes once I get this program going I will sit down and relearn some of the basics of Java again.

Comment: okay one last  issue. 
I have removed all the static issues from my code. But now I get the error "non-static method setDepartmentToSystem(Department)cannot be refrenced from a static context.

well fine my mainDriver had to be static that is the only way to declare so how would I reference it from a non static method.

Comment: @Binyomin That means you're calling it from a static method; it needs to be called from an instance--it's still a static issue.

Comment: I have declared my mainDriver like this to get the initial startup heppening
public static void main(String[] args)
 {
    new MainDriver();
  
 }

Comment: should I be declaring it as I would an object MainDriver theMainDriver = new MainDriver();

Comment: @Binyomin You shouldn't do all of `MainDriver`'s work in the constructor, rather something like `MainDriver md = new MainDriver(); md.go();` or whatever. Without seeing any code, I'd just be guessing.

Comment: aha it should be in a separate class totaly to the rest of the program?

Comment: @Binyomin Not necessarily; the `main` method of `MainDriver` can construct a `MainDriver` and use it; that's typical.

Comment: Thanks again Dave.
im getting their with it I will let u know how I go.

Comment: so if I declare MainDriver as theMainDriver and I want to pass a variable to one of its methods from a diffrent class. would I go theMainDriver.setEmployee(emp).

because I tried this and it did not work

Comment: @Binyomin Saying something "didn't work" isn't helpful. Yes, if you have an instance called `theMainDriver`, and there's a method called `setEmployee`, that takes a parameter of whatever type `emp` is, it will work. If it didn't, then either one of those conditions isn't met, or there was a runtime error. Please start a new question since this is completely unrelated to the original issue, and this is too many comments.

Answer (score 1):

Binyomin, i think your inner while controller makes wrong...

```
while (i < numberOfEmps1 ){ i++; }
```

I think this loop will traverse all the employees in the file. Then the next iteration of the inner loop will return EOF...

Try posting your file structure..

Comment: The outer loop reads in the number of employees and uses it to control the inner loop; it should stop after the correct number of employees are read in (assuming no data issues).